# Bind click event on class or id in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I have created some component in ReactJs. Which contains HTML code.
A component is Leaflets map.

```
/**
 * Draws zones control container.
 *
 * @param map
 *
 * @return void
 */
addZoneControl = (map) => {
    let categories = this.generateZoneCategories();
    let control = L.Control.extend({
        options: {
            position: 'topleft'
        },
        onAdd: function (map) {
            let container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-bar leaflet-control leaflet-control-custom');
            container.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            container.innerHTML = categories;
            container.id = 'categoriesContainer';
            container.onclick = function(){
                alert('buttonClicked');
            };
            return container;
        }
    });

    map.addControl(new control());
};
```

HTML code that has been imported into map control
(this HTML code are dynamically generated but now is written static for example)

```
/**
 * Generates HTML code from JSON data 
 * 
 * @return {string}
 */
generateZoneCategories = () => {
    return '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3" id="categories">' +
            '<p class="text-uppercase" id="filter">Ansicht Filtern</p>' +
            '<p class="category purple">1. Kategorie <span>CHF 78.00</span></p>' +
            '<p class="category orange">2. Kategorie <span>CHF 68.00</span></p>' +
            '<p class="category green">3. Kategorie <span>CHF 58.00</span></p>' +
            '<p class="category blue">4. Kategorie <span>CHF 48.00</span></p>' +
        '</div>'
};
```

ReactJs Component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import L from 'leaflet';

import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import './style.css';
import {childrenType, GridLayer} from 'react-leaflet'

class SeatMap extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let map = this.map = L.map(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this), {
            minZoom: -3,
            maxZoom: 3,
            crs: L.CRS.Simple,
            zoomsliderControl: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            attributionControl: false,
            doubleClickZoom: false,
        });

        this.addZoneControl(map);

        map.fitWorld();

        /* Here I want to bind click event on category class */
        console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode('.category').length);


       }
.
.
.
```

I wanted to do more stuff on click on element with category class.

With jQuery we know that it will be something like

```
$('.category').click(function () { /* magic */ });
```

I wonder how to do same magic in **ReactJs**?

Comment: By returning all that HTML you're not benefitting from the power of React. If you separated that HTML into components you could bind listeners to whatever one you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, I found something that could be helpful.

https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html
On this link, you can find what ReactJs recommends about the additional library.

General advice about the additional library like **`bootstrap`**, **`leaflet`** is to search for ReactJs optimized lib (with components) like react-bootstrap, react-leaflet. Or if there is no ReactJs optimized lib maybe is time to search for other solution.

All clickable elements on the page should be **`components`** in order to use ReactJs by the book and get all its benefits.

This topic is maybe of topic but there is a solution how to bind click on Components and get data from itself.

[Send data to ReactJs function via component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111859/send-data-to-reactjs-function-via-component)