# Send data to ReactJs function via component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I want to make nested component clickable and to know on which component is clicked.

I had tried to send variable but there are some issues.

If I write function with **`this.clickMe()`** it will be invoked at component load.
if the function is written in this way **`this.clickMe`** without rounded brackets, the click event is invoked but I can not pass a parameter.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CategoryControlRow from './components/CategoryControlRow';
import './style.css';

/**
 * @class ./widgets/SeatMap/components/LeafletMap/components/CategoryControl
 */
class CategoryControl extends Component
{
    /**
     * TODO: This function supposed to be deleted.
     */
    clickMe = (text) =>
    {
        alert(text);
    };

    /**
     * @returns {XML}
     */
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3" id="categories">
                <p className="text-uppercase" id="filter">Ansicht Filtern</p>

                <CategoryControlRow class={'category purple'} clickMe={this.clickMe} categoryName={'1. Kategorie'} currency={'CHF'} value={"78.00"} />
                <CategoryControlRow class={'category orange'} clickMe={this.clickMe} categoryName={'2. Kategorie '} currency={'CHF'} value={"68.00"} />
                <CategoryControlRow class={'category green'} clickMe={this.clickMe} categoryName={'3. Kategorie'} currency={'CHF'} value={"58.00"} />
                <CategoryControlRow class={'category blue'} clickMe={this.clickMe} categoryName={'4. Kategorie'} currency={'CHF'} value={"48.00"} />

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CategoryControl;
```

Sub Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';

/**
 * @class ./widgets/SeatMap/components/LeafletMap/components/CategoryControl/components/CategoryControlRow
 */
class CategoryControlRow extends Component
{
    /**
     * @returns {XML}
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <p className={"category " + this.props.class} onClick={this.props.clickMe}>
                {this.props.categoryName}
                <span>
                    {this.props.currency} {this.props.value}
                </span>
            </p>
        )
    }
}

export default CategoryControlRow;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `CategoryControl` component, add constructor below as following;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CategoryControlRow from './components/CategoryControlRow';
import './style.css';

class CategoryControl extends Component
{
    // Add this constructor
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this);
    }

    clickMe = (text) =>
    {
        alert(text);
    };

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-3" id="categories">
                <p className="text-uppercase" id="filter">Ansicht Filtern</p>

                <CategoryControlRow class={'category purple'} clickMe={this.clickMe} categoryName={'1. Kategorie'} currency={'CHF'} value={"78.00"} />
                <CategoryControlRow class={'category orange'} clickMe={this.clickMe} categoryName={'2. Kategorie '} currency={'CHF'} value={"68.00"} />
                <CategoryControlRow class={'category green'} clickMe={this.clickMe} categoryName={'3. Kategorie'} currency={'CHF'} value={"58.00"} />
                <CategoryControlRow class={'category blue'} clickMe={this.clickMe} categoryName={'4. Kategorie'} currency={'CHF'} value={"48.00"} />

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CategoryControl;
```

And for the `CategoryControlRow` sub component, add constructor, event handler function and edit your onClick attribute in `p` element as following;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';

class CategoryControlRow extends Component
{
    // Add this constructor
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    // Add this event handler function
    onClickParagraph = categoryName => {
        this.props.clickMe(categoryName);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <p className={"category " + this.props.class} 
               /* Edit onClick like this*/ 
               onClick={this.onClickParagraph.bind(this, this.props.class)}>
                  {this.props.categoryName.YOUR_FIELD_NAME}
                  <span>
                      {this.props.currency.YOUR_FIELD_NAME} 
                      {this.props.value.YOUR_FIELD_NAME}
                  </span>
            </p>
        )
    }
}

export default CategoryControlRow;
```

Answer (score 2):

Write it like this

```
<CategoryControlRow class={'category purple'} clickMe={(event) => this.clickMe(event, "value1", "value2")} categoryName={'1. Kategorie'} currency={'CHF'} value={"78.00"} />
```

Instead of value1 and value2, you can pass any number of arguments

Answer (score 1):

In your `CategoryControlRow`, you can do the following:

- Create a constructor, where you do `this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)`, to make it keep a reference to the correct "this"
- Create a function `onClick() { this.props.onClick(this.props.categoryName); }` or whatever data you want to use to identify your component
- Set `onClick={this.onClick}` on your p

Edit: you can use arrow function for onClick to avoid the `bind(this)` trick, but this has a *little* performance cost in many cases so I prefer the bind version.

Answer (score 1):

```
<CategoryControlRow class={'classname'} clickMe={(event) => this.clickMe(event, parameterlist)} categoryName={categoryobject} currency={currencyobj} value={valueobject} />
```

Every thing in child component you get as a props:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';

/**
 * @class ./widgets/SeatMap/components/LeafletMap/components/CategoryControl/components/CategoryControlRow
 */
class CategoryControlRow extends Component
{
    /**
     * @returns {XML}
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <p className={"category " + this.props.class} onClick={this.props.clickMe}>
                {this.props.categoryName.YOUR_FIELD_NAME}
                <span>
                    {this.props.currency.YOUR_FIELD_NAME} {this.props.value.YOUR_FIELD_NAME}
                </span>
            </p>
        )
    }
}

export default CategoryControlRow;
```

Answer (score 1):

the method:

```
clickMe = (e) =>{
    alert(e.target.whateverYouNeed);
}
```

The element:

```
<CategoryControlRow class={'category purple'} clickMe={(e)=>this.clickMe(e)} categoryName={'1. Kategorie'} currency={'CHF'} value={"78.00"} />
```